# Missing number, treated as zero in fancyhead

Tags: fancyhdr

I keep on getting  this error `Missing number, treated as zero.`
for following piece of code:

```
\fancyhead[CE]{\small\leftmark}{\textwidth}
\fancyhead[CO]{\small\rightmark}{\textwidth}
```

but not for this

```
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\thepage}
```

Why?

Comment: Please provide a working document, not just fragments of code! The upper version is wrong, since it tries to execute `\textwidth` which is a dimension register and can't be used this way! Besides that, `\fancyhead` does not have two mandatory argument, as far as I know!

Comment: Actually your last remark was enough to solve the problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is using

```
\fancyhead[CE]{\small\leftmark}{\textwidth}
\fancyhead[CO]{\small\rightmark}{\textwidth}
```

that way -- it's wrong for two reasons:

1. `\fancyhead` has no two mandatory arguments, just one optional and a mandatory one
2. `\textwidth` can't be called this way -- it's a `dimension` register and must either be used with other lengths or preceded by `\the\textwidth` (depending on the context!)